# SQL Query for accessing information from two separate tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables named `Articles` and `Publishers`

In `Article` table, there are multiple columns but there are 3 of note: `ArticleId`, `PublishDate`, and `AuthorName`.

In the `Publishers` table, there are also multiple columns but 2 of note: `ArticleId` and `HasPublisher`.

So for example if the `Article` table contains:

```
ArticleID   PublishDate  AuthorName
1              9/27/21     John
2              12/13/21   Smith
3               1/3/22.    Bob
```

and the `Publisher` table contains

```
ArticleID   HasPublisher
 1             Yes
 2             No
 3              Yes
```

What query will I have to run to check how many rows in the `Publisher` table has column `HasPublisher = yes` in which the same Id in the `Article` table has a publishDate column value of past date X.

So in this example if we want to fit criteria of date being past 9/26/21, the result would be 2 (Id = 1 and Id = 3 are value HasPublisher = Yes in the second table) but if we wanted to fit critera of date being past 1/1/22, the result would only be 1 entry (Id = 3).

Comment: Your Article does not have reference to Publisher table, so it's impossible to join then

Comment: So the Id column the two tables share will refer to the same "entry" or article

Comment: Ok, so now what have you tried? And what type of column is `PublishDate`? If it's string, then you have problems, better place timestamp there

Comment: I thought we'd moved on from 2-digit years since Y2k

Comment: @Stu No, it's still legit time format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select COUNT(p.*)
from Article a
inner join Publisher p on p.ArticleID = a.ArticleID
where p.HasPublisher = 'Yes' AND a.PublishDate > '2021-09-26'
```

Note how I formatted the date literal. If you're actually storing the dates as varchar columns in the 9/27/21 format, you're doing it wrong. The schema itself is **broken**, and you need to fix it. It is still possible to write this query with the broken schema, but the fixed version can take advantage of an index to run multiple orders of magnitude faster, and I promise you will save you much heartache in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Article art
INNER JOIN Publisher pub
ON  art.ArticleID   = pub.ArticleID 
WHERE PublishDate  > '2021-07-26'
AND HasPublisher = 'Yes'
```

You can inner join both the table on the ArticleId column and then filter on the criteria of HasPublisher and PublishDate.

Edit: Corrected the date format

Comment: `PublishDate  > '9/26/21'` is comparing strings, so `7/26/22` is less than `9/26/21`

Comment: Thanks @Justinas. Corrected the date format